# Passing two variables to one method to get two results

Tags: java, methods, initialization, global-variables

I am trying to pass two variables along to a method and have the method give me back two independent results.

```
int numX = 5;
int numY = 3;

System.out.println(displayTwiceTheNumber(numX, numY));

}
public static int displayTwiceTheNumber(int numX, int numY) {
    int numW, numZ;
    numW, numZ = 2 * (numX, numY);
    return numW numZ;        
}
```

Java takes it that at `numW, numZ = 2 * (numX, numY);` that I am trying to redefine `numX` and `numY`. How do I phrase the last block to take two variables and give two results?

Comment: Methods/functions do have one and only one returned value- A dirty way would be to return a list of results

Comment: *give two results* You can't

Comment: this is not correct Java syntax. But otherwise, your question about how to return two results / modify two parameters is unfortunately too broad - there are many ways to do this

Comment: define an Object to hold that 2 values, (or use one like `Point` - if that values happen to be coordinates; or even an array or list (not best IMO, but depends on actual use case))

Comment: If the is a connection between the two numbers returned, then make them into an object, like Point, or Complex. Otherwise I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

A single int function can only return 1 int at a time.
If you want to return 2 values, consider calling the function twice or creating a custom object to be used.

Comment: _creating a custom object to be used.._ +1!

Comment: Sometimes returning an array is a code smell, when these two returned values have a meaning inside the solution, so +1 to the custom object proposal. An object called `Pair` with two attributes is more meaningful than a mere `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the return type of the function. Currently, the return type is int, so you have to return one integer.

To return two integer, you should consider returning an array or a list or something similar.

```
public static int[] displayTwiceTheNumber(int numX, int numY){
//your code that do something
   int[] ret = {numW, numZ};
   return ret;
}
```

Or knowing that this function would change the value of numW and numZ, you could declare those as global variable. Now, when you call this function, those variable will be changed. Then, you can use numW and numZ subsequently.

```
public int numW;
public int numZ;

public static void displayTwiceTheNumber(int numX, int numY){
//your code that do something and modifies numW and numZ
}


public static void anotherfunction(){
   //after calling displayTwiceTheNumber, numW and numZ would have the appropriate value
   //you can now just use numW and numZ directly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview: Use a tuple.  In this example I use an tuple to return more than one result.  Tuple means to return more than one result type.   In this example I return a tuple of two integer types.  My class TupleCustom contains one method function1 which receives two parameters of type integer: x and y.   I create a tuple of type integer and return the tuple as a variable.  Internally, the precomiler converts the tuple json than back to a tuple with variable Item1, Item2...ItemN in the unit test method.

```
  public class TupleCustom
  {
    public async Task<Tuple<int, int>> Function1(int x, int y)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> retTuple = new Tuple<int, int>(x, y);
        await Task.Yield();
        return retTuple;
    }

}

public class TestSuite
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;
    public TestSuite(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestTuple()
    {
        TupleCustom custom = new TupleCustom();

        Tuple<int, int> mytuple = await custom.Function1(1,2);

        output.WriteLine($" Item1={mytuple.Item1} Item2={mytuple.Item2}  ");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problem I create a private utility class for handling the return values.  By doing it this way, you can pass various types in the argument list. Aspects of the class can be tailored to your requirements.

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int numX = 5;
        double numY = 3.0;

        Nums n = displayTwiceTheNumber(numX, numY);
        System.out.println(n.numX);
        System.out.println(n.numY);

    }
    public static Nums displayTwiceTheNumber(int numX, double numY) {
        int numW;
        double numZ;
        // do something with arguments.
        // in this case just double them and return.
        return new Nums(2*numX, 2*numY);        
    }

    private static class Nums {
        int numX;
        double numY;
        public Nums(int nx, double ny) {
            this.numX = nx;
            this.numY = ny;
        }
        public String toString() {
          return "(" + numX + ", " + numY +")";
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
10
6.0
```